# Spring Data JPA and Galera with MySQL (Percona) - Does the connection_id remain stable for the whole transaction?

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, percona, galera

I'm trying to understand if the `connection_id()` function returns the same `thread_id` for the whole duration of a Transactional annotated method on a Spring application.

I have a method which is annotated with Transactional like so:

```
@Transactional
  @KafkaListener(
      topics = "#{kafkaConfiguration.getTopic(T(full.package.to.FlightDaily))}")
  public void onMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<String, FlightDaily>> records) {
    consume(records, data -> {
      final FlightDaily update = data.value();
      LOG.log(Level.FINE, "Received Kafka Event, Flight - IataCode: {0}",
          update.getFlightNumberIata());
      processor.process(update);
    });
  }
```

Then, inside the processor, there are a series of operations and multiple entities are inserted / updated on the db.

The table related to one of the entities, has an Audit which is automatically populated by triggers. (`AFTER INSERT` and `AFTER UPDATE` inserts)

The trigger grabs the current connection_id with a

```
DECLARE current_conn_id BIGINT(20);
SET current_conn_id = (SELECT connection_id());
```

And then insert it as part of the Audit.

The problem is that I was expecting this connection_id to remain stable inside a Transaction.. because from my understanding, it is the thread currently serving my transaction (if the application opens one) but from the Audit content, it seems like it changes a lot and it doesn't remain stable.

I thought it may be that the Spring application is using multiple connections from the pool.. but it doesn't make sense to me that it uses multiple connections of the pool inside the same transaction, shouldn't a single connection remain locked / used by that transaction until it is committed / rolled back?

---

Update:

The application communicate with a single node of the Galera cluster, until (and if) that node stops working.

I tested my theory with a mysql client, manually starting a transaction and keeping the connection open.. and it seems to remain stable. But of course I have no pool of connections or the transaction automatically handled by the ransactional annotation.

Comment: Could it be that it uses the same connection to Galera but different between Galera and MySQL?

Comment: But from my understanding, the connection_id() is the thread on the server which is currently handling my connection and transaction.. I was expecting it to remain stable during a transaction

Comment: I'm no expert around this setup but I believe you are correct in assuming the JVM will run within its own thread for the duration of the transaction. However it means that the thread is connected to Galera and the trigger is run on MySQL so I'm thinking there might be something going on between the 2... Have you tried connecting to MySQL directly to see if you get the same issue?

Comment: Not sure of what you mean, but the application requests are all going to the same node of the Galera cluster (unless it stops working). Regarding the JVM thread instead, I'm more interested into the server-side thread which I think MySQL keeps open for the duration of the connection opened by Spring in the pool. What I was expecting is that each connection opened by the application pool has a single thread on server-side that handles it.. which is why I was expecting what I said in the question.

Comment: Application and database level transactions can be different.

Comment: In what way? Once I open a transaction on a db with a Transactional annotation, until I commit or roll it back, can it uses multiple threads, server side (AKA MySQL side)?

Comment: Is there an "auto-reconnect" setting somewhere (JPA, Galera, proxy server, etc)?  Is JPA really cognizant of "transactions"?  How?